# Ajustar un <p> junto a un <h3>

Tags: html, css

Estaria necesitando poner el "p" justo al costado del "h3" sin que el texto se ajuste y se coloque bajo el nivel del "h3", estuve intentando de distintas formas ajustando el display tanto del h3 como del p en inline-block pero nada. La 3ra foto es como deberia quedar.

Ahora al poner el Texto antes que el H3 en el .html si se ponen al mismo nivel.

```css
#cv_Info p{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1vw;
    width: 72%;
    margin: 0 0 0 12vw;
}

h3 {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.cv_Datablock {
    margin: 0 0 1.5vw 0;
}

.stripe2 {
    margin: 0 0.5vw 0 1vw;
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
    height: 0.4vw;
    background-color: #3c0d99;
}
```

```html
<div class="cv_Datablock">
            <div class="stripe2"></div>

            <h3>HISTORIAL<br>ACADEMICO</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates asperiores officia eum eaque deleniti enim vel quia blanditiis! Perspiciatis iusto officia natus quae cupiditate, commodi eum vero animi nisi corrupti.</p>

        </div>
```

[[image: Imagen Demostrativa1]
[image: Imagen Demostrativa]
[image: Imagen Demostrativa]

Comment: Veo las imágenes pero no tengo claro cual de ellas es el resultado esperado. O ninguna es el resultado esperado?? Haz aunque sea un montaje con paint de cómo quieres que quede, si no, cómo vamos a saber qué hacer para ayudarte???

Comment: Lo explicaba en el Texto, igualmente tenes razon, es dificil entenderlo solo con palabras. Ahi agregue la 3ra imagen de como deberia de quedar, la idea es que el texto no ajuste su altura por el H3.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar Grid para determinar el lugar de cada elemento. Tambien puedes utilizar la propiedad `grid-template-areas` para especificar un nombre a cada lugar. Por ejemplo, este layout:

```
------------------------
|       |     linea    |
|       |--------------|
| titulo|              |  
|       |     texto    |
|       |              |
------------------------
```

Demo:

```css
#cv_Info p{
    grid-area: texto;
}

h3 {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    grid-area: titulo;
}

.cv_Datablock {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max(140px,12vw) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.4vw 1fr; 
    gap: 0px 0px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "titulo linea"
    "titulo texto"; 
}

.stripe2 {
    background-color: #3c0d99;
    grid-area: linea;
}

.container {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 222px 334px; 
  gap: 0px 0px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "titulo linea"
    "titulo texto"; 
}
```

```html
<div class="cv_Datablock">

  <div class="stripe2"></div>

  <h3>HISTORIAL ACADEMICO</h3>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates asperiores officia eum eaque deleniti enim vel quia blanditiis! Perspiciatis iusto officia natus quae cupiditate, commodi eum vero animi nisi corrupti.</p>

</div>
```

Nota: Ojo con las unidades relativas en `font-size`, entiendo que quieres unas dimensiones dinámicas, pero me parece que deberías usar [clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp)

Answer (score 1):

Con contenedores flex y con HTML y clases un poco mas semánticas y autodescriptivas:

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;
  height: min-content;
  width: 100%;
}

.section_title {
  margin: 2px 5px;
}

.section_body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: min-content;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.section_body_stripe {
  height: 0.4vw;
  background-color: #3c0d99;
}
```

```html
  <article class="section">
    <h3 class="section_title">HISTORIAL<br>ACADEMICO</h3>
    <div class="section_body">
      <div class="section_body_stripe"></div>
      <p class="section_body_paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates asperiores officia eum eaque deleniti enim vel quia blanditiis! Perspiciatis iusto officia natus quae cupiditate, commodi eum vero animi nisi corrupti.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
```